# Autoformat Javascript in Netbeans IDE

Tags: javascript, netbeans, autoformatting

Are there any known Plugins or ways to properly autoformat Javascript in Netbeans IDE?

Comment: Select the text>> right click >> format

Comment: Not really helpful because that only apply's the most basic formatting (if at all). There must be a way to adjust those settings or customize them? The options menu only reveals a php section and a section for "all languages".

Comment: Actually, after months of searching for one I finally built one.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43263/jsbeautify

It uses jsbeautify.js to format javascript.  I'm looking into html formatting next.

Comment: Cool thing, I'll definately give it a try!

Comment: @DrewH could you implement more options like keep the opening curly bracket after a function conditional on the same line as the closing bracket (seperated from the ')' by one space?

Comment: @junior it should do this by default actually.  If it's not then I need to change it.  It should be collapse by default, meaning that it will put curly brace on the same line as a function.  Expand will put it below the function(C++, C# style).  I've implemented 90% of the options that jsbeautify has.
http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Edit:  I think understand what your saying now.  If your talking about the option "end braces on own line".  Yes I will add that.  I'll post here when I'm done.

Comment: @DrewH Found out that "collapse (Brace style) is actually what I wanted to achive". The Plugin does its job so far except for one thing atm: the last newline at the end of the file gets deleted no matter if the "preserve new lines" option is opted in or not. Would be nice if the netbeans autoformat hotkey shift+alt+f would work too. Please Answer so that I can accept yours!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT 9/15/2012**

After looking into this further, I have found that the javascript module is being rewritten already(much needed).  You can finally find formatting options for javascript.  It's available in the netbeans nightly builds.  Good luck all.

http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/

I have released a pretty simple JS formatter that uses JSBeautify and runs in Rhino.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43263/jsbeautify

You have to use an alternate key for now.  I'm working on modifying the Javascript language in Netbeans to possibly release something better, later on(either as a plugin or patch).  I'm still familiarizing myself with the way things are happening in Netbeans.

There have been talks for years to add more formatting options for Javascript in Netbeans.  Nothing has surfaced.  I'm going to propose that the Javascript language leverage JSBeautify(running in Rhino) to provide formatting, rather then implementing new features in Java.  This simplifies the formatting process, plus the JSBeautify community is very large and it's actively developed.

Comment: Really great plugin Drew. Just a quick question: How can I give it indent size (spaces) for 3? It only shows a drop-list with static options: 2, 4, 8... Or at least some way to left the spaces decision to default Netbeans behavior... cheers!

Comment: Hey Santiago, thanks for your interest. I need to add that.  I'll post back here when it's ready.  Really the correct way to do things is patch the current Javascript module and release it as a plugin, that's kind of what I'm working on now.  This was more a proof of concept and workaround, cause I needed it for myself quickly.  Haha.

Comment: is this plugin abandoned? or is there plan to update for 8.2?