# JS code obfuscation in netbean

Tags: javascript, netbeans

how to solve javascript code obfuscation in Netbeans. Code is not format and unable to read.Please help my problem .

```
    function dumptbl(obj, row_callback_str, cell_callback_str) {
    dw('<table border=1>');
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
        var tr = '<tr>';
        eval(row_callback_str);
        dw(tr);
        for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].length; ++j) {
            var td_s = '<td>',
                td_e = '</td>';
            eval(cell_callback_str);
            dw(td_s);
            dw(obj[i][j]);
            dw(td_e);
        }
    }
    dw('</table>');
}
```

Comment: paste it into jsfiddle.net javascript window - click on `tidy` button

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: @PranavSingh I think the *"bad formatting"* was part of the question :D

Comment: @user3156613, I don't what you mean by obfuscation of js but if you mean minification reverse is called beautification. http://jsbeautifier.org/ see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096777/autoformat-javascript-in-netbeans-ide

Comment: thank you so much..